# Form to fill excel spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, excel

I've been trying to build an application to submit form selections to an existing spreadsheet on a local machine. This is intended for a windows machine, but I am working on ubuntu, and don't have access to a windows development environment. With this, I'm trying to parse an excel document, find the bottom row, capture the 'ingredients' list, or other form values, then insert the value of the hash into the excel column and save the changes to the document. Any suggestions on where I should start would be great. 
-- Thanks a million

```js
//Script
$(document).ready(doInput);
function doInput(){
  var ingreds = $('.ingredients');
  var count = $('.count');
  var runs = $('#runs');
  var cb = $('.cb');
  var bb = $('.bb');
  var fullDate = new Date();
  var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
  var currentDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getDate() + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
  var bbDate = fullDate.getMonth() + 8;
  cb.html("C&B:<br />" + currentDate);
  if (bbDate > 12){
    bb.html("BB:<br />" + "0" + (bbDate - 12) + "/" + fullDate.getDate() + "/" + (fullDate.getFullYear() + 1));
  }else{
    bb.html("Best By:<br />" + bbDate + "/" + fullDate.getDate() + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear());
  }
  var recipes = {
    'Volvo': {
      'Torq': 1231,
      'Leather': 131,
      'Blue': 22
    },
    'Jet': {
      'HP': 1233,
      'Leather': 121,
      'Candy': 1313,
      'Gas': 1313,
      'Billiard': 223
    },
    'Mac': {
      'Torq': 12111,
      'Cheddar': 123
    },
    'Hog': {
      'Torq': 475,
      'Sugar': 12,
      'Sheer': 11,
      'Water': 2323,
      'Wheels': 3
    }
  }
  var recipe;
  ingreds.html("Ingredients:<br />");
  count.html("The Yield is:" + $('#yield').val() + "?<br />");
  if ($("option:selected").val() == 'volv') {
    recipe = recipes['Volvo'];
  }else if($("option:selected").val() == 'jet') {
    recipe = recipes['Jet'];
  }else if($("option:selected").val() == 'mac') {
    recipe = recipes['Mac'];
  }else if($("option:selected").val() == 'hog') {
    recipe = recipes['Hog'];
  }
  for (key in recipe){
    if(key == 'Sugar'){
      ingreds.append(key + ": " + recipe[key] * runs.val() + 'Lbs<br />');
    }else{
      ingreds.append(key + ": " + recipe[key] * runs.val() + 'g<br />');
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
   
body {
  background: rgba(150,150,150,.5);
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.ingredients {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.count {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-weight: Bold;
  color: #700;
}
.submit, 
.ingredients, 
.flavor,
.runs,
.yieldShell,
.bestBy,
.cb,
.bb {
  min-width: 215px;
}
.count {
  min-width: 190px;
}
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
.col-sm-4{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form oninput="doInput()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flavor col-sm-4">
        Flavor:<br />
        <select name="flavors">
          <option value="volv" selected="selected">Volvo</option>
          <option value="jet">Jet</option>
          <option value="mac">Mac</option>
          <option value="hog">Hog</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="runs col-sm-4">
        Number of runs:<br />
        <input type="number" id="runs" name="runs" value="1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ingredients col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="yieldShell col-sm-4">
        <div class="yield">Yield:<br />
          <input type="number" id="yield" name="yield" value="450">
        </div>
        <div class="count col-sm-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="submit col-sm-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Save to Production Log?">
      </div>
      <div class="bestBy col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 cb"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 bb"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not looking at this from the wrong angle?

Rarely would you try to access an Excel document directly, since the quantity of 'irrelevant' data is huge (data needed by Excel to reconstruct the page itself, but not directly related to the data the user is storing - meta-data if you will; i.e. font used, size of font, etc.).

Usually you would output the data to a CSV and allow the user to import the data into any spreadsheet program, which gives you greater flexibility and is simpler to code.

In terms of adding the data, you could easily open the existing CSV and append new data, or search the file and insert the data where required. However, if others are to use the CSV then I'd save the data in a single-table database as well as in the CSV. Then you simply construct a new CSV each time, overwriting any existing file if necessary.

No code help here at present, and I might be wrong, but this is the approach I have used and seen used.